# Is a barber liable for messing up a haircut?

Tags: liability, civil-law

If a barber accidentally gives someone a bad haircut, causing them to miss a meeting and contract, can the person sue for damages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they could sue either for breach of contract or under the tort of negligence. If they succeed, they would be entitled to either a) a refund or b) another haircut.

They would not be entitled to damages for "miss a meeting and contract" as these are not foreseeable results of a bad haircut. That is, the barber's negligence is not sufficiently proximate to the loss.

Comment: What if you ask the barber to do a good job; that a certain amount of money depends on it.

Comment: @jqning Asking the barber to do a good job is an admission that you understand that a bad haircut is possible. I could even argue that it implies that a bad haircut is probable! A good job should be assumed, not requested. That will ruin your case. If it's that important, get your hair cut by someone you KNOW will do a good job.